# How do I remove accounts I've added in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I have added my Gmail account to outlook.com and want to know how to remove it. I have gone to accounts *Inbox* → *Options* → *Your email accounts* and then clicked on *Details* for the selected account but nothing happens. Is there another way that I can remove the Gmail account from outlook.com?

[image: The account I want to remove]

Comment: Please join me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access I will be able to help you there.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to go to `Account Settings` you will see the following information.  I have removed my aliases for obvious reasons.

[image]

So click "Add or Change Aliases" and you will get the following screen.

[image]

At this point you add/remove your aliases.

You might also be talking about how you linked your Google Account to your Outlook Account.  If thats the case the following screen is where you want to be:

[image]

Just click on "Manage other accounts" and you will be provided a way to remove the connection.  You can also disconnect from within the Google Account itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the second option is what I was wanting to see but when I then go back into "Your email accounts" I can still see the Gmail account in "Accounts you've added". And after I removed the gmail account the outlook.com suddenly syncd 3more emails I reveived in gmail this morning

Comment: @WillNZ - Post a screenshot.  It will help me figure out what you are talking about exactly.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the question. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is how to do it: In **Options** / **Your email accounts**, click on "**Details**" for the account you want to remove; there will be a pop up with two choices: "**Account Settings**" and "**Remove**" (which is gray).   Click the **Remove** choice and click **Remove** again when it asks for confirmation.